# How to make visionOS simulator available in Xcode beta?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, visionos

Developing an app for visionOS. I did both, downloading inside Xcode visionOS, and did it externally from download.apple.com. I waited for both. Both was downloaded. 2 x 7GB.

Yesterday I even could run a HelloWorld app. I restarted the computer and again I can not run.

1. Shall I download again from Xcode? Why it was disappeared?
2. Can I do something with `visionOS_1_beta_2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg` I mounted it, but it did not "triggered" anything in Xcode to run the app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I encountered the same problem and had to download it again from Xcode in order to fix it.

Comment: I hope I do not have to download again after this now. Did you also restarted Mac?

Comment: Yes I restarted it

Comment: Have you face with these challenges maybe?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817570/how-to-add-realitykitcontent-to-an-existing-swiftui-app

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817663/will-tabview-not-be-visible-if-realitykitcontent-is-not-imported-in-swiftui-app