# Will TabView not be visible if RealityKitContent is not imported in SwiftUI app?

Tags: swiftui, visionos

Have an existing SwiftUI app and wants to port to visionOS also.

If I do not import `RealityKitContent` related parts from Apple's HelloWord app, then ui will appear, app will start in visionOS simulator, but tabbar does not visible, why? How to solve?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
//import RealityKitContent
```

```swift
//ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    
    
    //@Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) var openImmersiveSpace
    //@Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) var dismissImmersiveSpace



    var body: some View {
        
        
        TabView {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    Text("Item")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            } detail: {
                VStack {
                   

                    Text("Hello, world!")

                    /*Toggle("Show ImmersiveSpace", isOn: $showImmersiveSpace)
                        .toggleStyle(.button)
                        .padding(.top, 50)*/
                }
                .navigationTitle("Content")
                .padding()
            }
            /*.onChange(of: showImmersiveSpace) { _, newValue in
                Task {
                    if newValue {
                        await openImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace")
                    } else {
                        await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                    }
                }
            }*/
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            List {
                Text("Item")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// DataMapperApp.swift

//
//  DataMapperApp.swift
//  DataMapper
//
//  Created by János Kukoda on 2023. 01. 10..
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct DataMapperApp: App {
    var sharedState = SharedState() // create an instance of SharedState
    
    init() {
        // Set color scheme to dark mode
        UITraitCollection.current = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(sharedState).colorScheme(.dark)
        }
        
        /*ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ImmersiveView()
        }*/
    }
}
```

[image]

When I run same code, not commented in Apple's HelloWorld environment:

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  VisionOS
//
//  Created by János Kukoda on 2023. 08. 01..
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImmersiveSpace = false

    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) var openImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) var dismissImmersiveSpace

    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    Text("Item")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            } detail: {
                VStack {
                    Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)

                    Text("Hello, world!")

                    Toggle("Show ImmersiveSpace", isOn: $showImmersiveSpace)
                        .toggleStyle(.button)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Content")
                .padding()
            }
            .onChange(of: showImmersiveSpace) { _, newValue in
                Task {
                    if newValue {
                        await openImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace")
                    } else {
                        await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            List {
                Text("Item")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

then tabbar visible:

[image]

A slightly different but connecting question: [How to add RealityKitContent to an existing SwiftUI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817570/how-to-add-realitykitcontent-to-an-existing-swiftui-app)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found how to import RealityKitContent is to make a new visionOS project, copy over the RealityKitContent package to my existing app. Then add it is a local package...

There seems like there should be a better way, but this worked.